# Is this a safety or fire hazard

Tags: electrical, safety, installation, garbage-disposal, fire-hazard

My apartment complex recently replaced the disposal in my kitchen that was leaking from the power cord due to a cracked seal. They left the wires of the power cord that attach to the disposal exposed and I’m worried it may be a fire hazard. [image]

Comment: What city/state/province/country? I don't think there's anywhere in the US this work would be legal.

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly an electrical code violation, and electrical code is about both fire and shock prevention.

If the building's head of maintenance doesn't immediately get this corrected, send the picture along to the local inspection authority.

Mind you, a landlord having electrical work done by anyone other than a licensed electrician is also a violation, at least in the USA. And if a licensed electrician did that, their license should be *under review by their licensing board* so I imagine it wasn't actually done by one. Some places do grant plumbers limited electrical licenses for plumbing related electricity, but if they did this, again, they should be hauled on the carpet in front of a board with the authority to revoke that license.

Comment: And did you notice where it comes out of the wall? It looks like he snaked some romex through a piece of cable armor.

Comment: No, that's AC, MC, MC-Lite or BX armored cable, perfectly normal in a Multiple Dwelling Unit (apartment or multifamily building - higher standards for fire prevention.) But the fitting needs to be properly connected, and whoever did this couldn't be bothered.

Comment: The armor stops with a mangled cut before it enters the wall cavity.

Comment: Can you sheath romex for protection? I think that's a no. Needs to be a box on the wall, and the red tag from the plastic bushings has to be showing on both ends. It's also supposed to be switched for a disconnect. - Tab not engaged into fitting; strike four.